# Converting a list of strings into a nested list of floats and strings skipping the first item

Tags: python, list, nested

I want to convert a certain list of strings into separated lists inside another list, which will contain strings and floats.
I've tried to use the `append` method to get the result, but I'm having trouble on making the nested list. Is there a way to get only the last line of my `output` as the result? This is my code:

```
def func(L):
    n = []
    lists = [i.split(',') for i in L]
    for xlist in lists:
        xlist[1:] = [float(item) for item in xlist[1:]]
        n.append(xlist)
        print(n)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func(['PersonX, 10, 92, 70', 'PersonY, 60, 70', 'PersonZ, 98.5, 1100, 95.5, 38'])
    

OUTPUT: [['PersonX', 10.0, 92.0, 70.0]]
        [['PersonX', 10.0, 92.0, 70.0], ['PersonY', 60.0, 70.0]]
        [['PersonX', 10.0, 92.0, 70.0], ['PersonY', 60.0, 70.0], ['PersonZ', 98.5, 1100.0, 95.5, 38.0]]


EXPECTED OUTPUT: [['PersonX', 10.0, 92.0, 70.0], ['PersonY', 60.0, 70.0], ['PersonZ', 98.5, 1100.0, 95.5, 38.0]]
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use some list [unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) and list concatenation to accomplish the result you are looking for:

```
def func(L):
    n = []
    for value in L:
        a, *b = value.split(',')
        n.append([a] + [float(item) for item in b])
    print(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just unindent the `print` outside of the loop to only perform the operation once at the end:

```
def func(L):
    n = []
    lists = [i.split(',') for i in L]
    for xlist in lists:
        xlist[1:] = [float(item) for item in xlist[1:]]
        n.append(xlist)
    print(n)
```

*Note however that by using `print`, you don't really output a list with integers. You should rather use `return n`*